# Lightgbm how to fix number of step

Tags: python, scikit-learn, lightgbm

I am currently using lightgbm library on python.

```
model = lgb.LGBMRegressor(objective='regression', metric='rmse', boosting_type='rf', max_depth=20, num_leaves=20,
                          learning_rate=0.1, feature_fraction=0.8, feature_fraction_seed=10, bagging_fraction=0.8,
                          bagging_freq=1, bagging_seed=10, verbosity=True,
                          lambda_l2=0.000001, lambda_l1=0.00001, max_bin=200)
model.fit(X_train, np.log1p(y_train), num_iteration=1000, eval_set=[(X_val, np.log1p(y_val) )], eval_metric="rmse", verbose=True, early_stopping_rounds=20)
```

The problem is that, the training stop after 100 iterations. I did not find on the documentation a step parameters, so I was wondering how can I increase the number of iteration? I do not want to use the lgb.train() function. In fact, I want also to use  a Grid Search function from sklearn (and get the model then) so I need to use the fit function. Dos anyone know how to solve my problem ?

EDIT : It seems possible with the num_iterations parameters, but we need the last version of lightgbm. My former version did not work because of that !

Answer (score 0):

`n_estimators` is the parameter **of the model constructor** in sklearn API, that controls the number of trees to be built. You can also set it via `model.set_params()`.

Comment: I think OP asked about param to increase number of iteration.

Comment: @JanmejayaNanda In sklearn API of lightgbm the number of trees (what OP seems to call "number of iterations") is controlled by the `n_estimators` parameter, see [this link](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pythonapi/lightgbm.LGBMModel.html#lightgbm.LGBMModel.__init__). The only argument with "iteration" in the name is `num_iteration` in the `predict()` method, but it has nothing to do with training, but only with prediction step. This is true for the latest release at least

Comment: As i understand OP asked about `num_iteration` over training data.

Comment: @JanmejayaNanda could you please point me at this parameter in the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

You have set `early_stopping_rounds=20`, which means that training will stop if you get no improvement for the validation data in the last 20 iterations. This is used to avoid over-fitting, but may stop training early if set too low.